# Regarding understanding differential geometry

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am essentially looking for a book that would hold my hand through basic concepts to more complicated ones. I am coming from physics. I am looking to make some connections with Classical mechanics and or quantum field theory. I have been told that QFT is really just geometry and have only seen a few manifest aspects of that. I must say I am not any kind of expert. I want to be one though. I am looking for a short book.  I also want to be able to understand the whole complex cohomology and homology thing. I am guessing most of you know what I am talking about. Are there any books out there? Again, I am wanting to hold back on rigor and proofs to first get the concepts down well. Any video lecture links would be highly appreciated too.
    I am trying to study them for the next couple of months say three or four. Differential geometry and topology are things I would love to be invisible at. . .  So please help me out. Recommend some books and video links. Feel free to throw any Yang- Mills material at me too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't research level mathematics. You should consider [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) on the StackExchange site. There are several questions there which are similar to your request.

Comment: The answer depends a great deal on your background, but you might look at Clifford Taubes's book Differential Geometry: Bundles, Connections, Metrics and Curvature. It covers differential geometry with an eye to mathematical physics.

Comment: Whoever told you QFT is really just geometry, is definitely not a physicist...

Comment: I don't think any geometer believes that QFT is really just geometry. Geometers look at QFT with great awe and utter incomprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the books "Topology, Geometry, and Gauge Fields: Foundations" and "Topology, Geometry, and Gauge Fields: Interactions" are exactly what you're looking for.  They are not short, but you don't actually want a short book anyway because the only way to write a short differential geometry book is to give few terse examples and leave all the calculations to the reader.  That's good once you have a foothold but frustrating at first.  Mathematically, the books start with basically nothing and get through:

-Basic differential geometry: manifolds, Lie groups, connections on principal bundles, spin geometry
-Basic algebraic topology: de Rham cohomology, Chern-Weil theory, basic homotopy theory, classification of principal bundles

Physically, it covers the rudiments of gauge theory up through the beginnings of Donaldson theory / Yang-Mills theory ("Foundations") and the beginnings of Seiberg-Witten theory ("Interactions").  It gives *tons* of detailed examples and exercises throughout, including some examples that you don't often see in textbooks (like the quaternionic Hopf fibration).

To decide if the books are for you, I would recommend just finding a copy of "Foundations" and reading Chapter 0 - it is a bird's eye view of the subject which sets the tone for the rest of the series.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following books will be helpful:
The Geometry of Physics: An Introduction, by Theodore Frankel.
Geometry, Topology and Physics, by Mikio Nakahara.

For a quick introduction into the subject I would recommend (not physics oriented) 
Elementary Differential Geometry, by Andrew Pressley.

And finally, as the geometry of physics (both general relativity and gauge theory) is really a Cartan geometry, the following book (alas, also not physics oriented) is worth to mention:
Cartan for Beginners: Differential Geometry Via Moving Frames and Exterior Differential Systems, by  Thomas A. Ivey and J. M. Landsberg.